# Exporting site configurations for import to new websites - separate databases

Tags: config, configuration

Is it possible to export the site configurations of one website in terms of the site structures, not the content, for importing into another site with a separate database, essentially creating a site installation profile, similar to that possible in Drupal?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a great use-case for [Project Config](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/project-config.html)!

It's a file-based representation of your site's settings and information architecture without the content.

Get your boilerplate Project Config setup, then copy the `config/project` files to a new site and use it as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Brad, this is what Project Config is for. A great example to look at would be https://github.com/nystudio107/craft.